# UISearchBar in iOS 8 - UI displacement

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I have UINavigationItem and I want to add UISearchBar to it. Here's how I'm doing that:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.width, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height))
//searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
let barWrapper = UIView(frame: searchBar.frame)
barWrapper.addSubview(searchBar)
self.navigationItem.titleView = barWrapper
```

Here's result:[image]

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeToFit() will make the UIScrollView just big enough to fit its subviews.

You need to size it to fit the navigation bar to get rid of the gaps.

**EDIT**

If you're not using the nav bar for navigation, try just putting the search bar directly in your view. You'll have full control over the frame that way.

Comment: P.S. UISearchBar is a subclass of UIView so you probably don't need to put it in another UIView before you set it to the titleView.

Comment: It won't matter that you initialize it with a frame if you call sizeToFit() afterwards. sizeToFit() changes the frame.

Comment: Sorry, I understand, updated question again - the same

Comment: It might be that the titleView has a displacement from the left side of the navigationBar's frame. Do you need to put the search bar in the navigation bar?

Comment: Ok, how to put it on navigation bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83465/discussion-between-spongessuck-and-nikita-zernov).